# inserting data into mysql database through xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml, phpmyadmin

while i am inserting data into database using normal xml tree structure data is successfully inserted but while i am trying to insert data into database using different xml structure it is not gives me any error but at the same time fields are created but i can't visualize content in table to,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
<draw>
<candelete>yes</candelete>
<forpayroll>no</forpayroll>
<name>hello</name>
</draw>
</xml>
```

above xml format which successfully insert data into mysql database

below xml format is not allowing me to insert data into mysql database

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<VERSION>1</VERSION>
<STATUS>1</STATUS>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<DESC>
</DESC>
<DATA>
<TALLYMESSAGE>
<LEDGER NAME="Dena" RESERVEDNAME="" ID="2240" REQNAME="dena">
<PARENT TYPE="String">Bank Accounts</PARENT>
<TAXTYPE TYPE="String">Others</TAXTYPE>
<ISBILLWISEON TYPE="Logical">No</ISBILLWISEON>
<ISCOSTCENTRESON TYPE="Logical">No</ISCOSTCENTRESON>
<ISREVENUE TYPE="Logical">No</ISREVENUE>
<ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE TYPE="Logical">Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
<CANDELETE TYPE="Logical">Yes</CANDELETE>
<FORPAYROLL TYPE="Logical">No</FORPAYROLL>
<MASTERID TYPE="Number"> 2240</MASTERID>
<TNETBALANCE TYPE="Amount">0.00</TNETBALANCE>
<LANGUAGENAME.LIST>
<NAME.LIST TYPE="String">
<NAME>Dena</NAME>
</NAME.LIST>
<LANGUAGEID TYPE="Number">0</LANGUAGEID>
</LANGUAGENAME.LIST>
</LEDGER>
</TALLYMESSAGE>
</DATA>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

below is my php insert connection code

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("temp", $con);


if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file('./xml/data.xml')){
trigger_error('Error reading XML file',E_USER_ERROR);
}



foreach ($xml as $syn) 
{
$candelete = $syn->candelete;  
$forpayroll = $syn->forpayroll;  
$name = $syn->name;

$sql    = "INSERT INTO vtiger (candelete, forpayroll, name) VALUES  ('$candelete','$forpayroll','$name')";
$query  = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$query)
{
    echo ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
else 
{
    echo "Record added";
}
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: please add some code of your import function, we cannot help you without code

Comment: i have mension my database connection code above, just edited. (i want to include 2 3 specific fields only so taken those fields only in connection)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like you to look at your `foreach` loop to read xml:

```
foreach ($xml as $syn) 
{
    $candelete = $syn->candelete;  
    $forpayroll = $syn->forpayroll;  
    $name = $syn->name;
```

as you see here you decleare xml nodes wich are totally different in new xml, so you need to parse your document and get all relevant data to build the query. A good approch would be to loop among `<TALLYMESSAGE>` to retrieve all relevant data and store into variables wich you will be able to use for the new query.

You can use `simplexml_load_file` to do that.
**Documentation:** [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

**NOTE** You query also must be changed according with new xml, you will need a new table with a correct schema.

`UPDATED`

You can still use the same way to parse file but you need to change your script and you will end up with more lines of code to parse the entire new xml. As you can see structure is totally different hand have many child nodes wich cannot be retrieved by using a simple foreach as you did for the first file wich didn't have any child nodes. That's why you really should use simplexml_load_file, less work

Comment: i get what you are saying and also thinking about doing same but posted question that if i can do what i want to do directly without doing all that'w why posted the question, still thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: yes you can but you totally need to change your script and you will end up with more lines of code to parse the entire new xml. As you can see structure is totally different hand have many child nodes wich cannot be retrieved by using a simple foreach as you did for the first file. That's why you really should use simplexml_load_file, less work

Comment: you welcome, if the answer is correct please accept it for future people with similar problems

Comment: Same from my side Fabio if you think that the question was valid then just up the question i don't know why somebody down graded this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think more about your foreach loop, bcause in your working xml file thats only one array so you can retrieve data using only one foreach loop, but your another xml file i think it contains more array so you need to create one or more foreach loop according to its structure.

Answer (score 0):

you define your conection to mysql in `$con`
you must also use `mysql_query($sql, $con);`

Comment: in very first xml format data is inserted so the problem is not about connection the problem is about XML structure, is it possible to inserting data using 2nd xml structure?